# Background size 100% auto not working in IE 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I've got some layers of divs with svg backgrounds. Set at 100% width and auto height:

```
  <div class="group section hot-bonus">
    <div class="layer layer-base clouds"></div>
    <div class="layer layer-back1 clouds-1"></div>
    <div class="layer layer-back2 clouds-2"></div>
    <div class="layer layer-back3 clouds-3"></div>
    <div class="layer layer-back5 bg"></div>
  </div>
```

The `.group` has these styles:

```
height: 65%;
z-index: 8;
text-align: center;
```

All of the clouds follow this format:

```
.clouds {
    z-index: 6;
    background: url(../images/hot_bonus_clouds.svg) center bottom no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    @include transform( scale(1.1) );
}
```

The result is this (full width browser screenshot): [image]

However, I can't seem to get it working on IE10. This is what it's giving me (never mind the design/layout differences, just the unstretched cloud backgrounds):

[image]

And this is despite IE10 showing that they have the style `background-size: 100% auto;` applied.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Is the .clouds container and any parent containers set to 100% width? It might be better if you showed more of your code structure.

Comment: I've updated the OP a little, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840551/background-size-with-svg-squished-in-ie9-10

Comment: Hi Christina, thanks for your input - that link did it!

Answer (score 2):

Answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22970897/1192861

> Be sure that your SVG has a width and height

I generated my SVG's from illustrator, I had to open them up again and set a width/height for each one. A really quick way to set it was to pay attention to this part of the svg element:

`viewBox="0 0 1428.5 521.8"` where `1428.5` is the width and `521.8` is the height. So the fix makes sure the SVG element looks something like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1428.5 521.8" width="1428.5" height="521.8"....>/***/</svg>
```