# background svg image becomes small in all IE

Tags: html, css, svg

I set a background image on a li element. The background image is a svg image. When I set it, it becomes super-small, and is positioned top-left. The error is isolated to IE only. I have tested in IE 8/9/10/11.

Here is the CSS of the background image:

```
background: transparent url("../images/icons/noglehul.svg") no-repeat scroll center center;
background-size: 17px 17px;
```

Here is the CSS on the li element:

```
float: left;
display: inline-block;
height: 17px;
width: 19px;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840551/background-size-with-svg-squished-in-ie9-10