# background svg issue in ie10 & 11

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, background, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

There seems to be a svg issue in ie with displaying background image from an assets folder. Some svg portions work while other parts don't. It works fine in all other browsers except ie. The css background is similar to the following:

```
.mark--title {
  background: url(/assets/img/icon_sprite.svg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center -291px;
}
```

Screenshots here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx7zRq6VPJISSGNBVmxscWIxclU/view?usp=sharing -
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx7zRq6VPJISNkNoSTQ1aDFrdG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There's not enough here to go on, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would certainly help, but perhaps this is your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840551/background-size-with-svg-squished-in-ie9-10

Comment: Thanks, sorry about the lack of info. Wasn't sure where to start as I tried most of what I know. Such as adding background-size to see if that worked. Resaving the svg. The svg works completely with other browsers and some parts of the sprite work. I use sketch to create my svg sprites. Below I have my opening svg line. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="637px" height="1069px" viewBox="0 0 637 1069" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">

Comment: Saved the svg through illustrator instead of sketch which has solve the issue. So not sure what it was, but it fixed it.

Comment: @ScottCarlton If you're generating it from Illustrator, ensure that the "Responsive" box is unchecked as this option removes width and height. if its unchecked it will work in IE.