# IE11 wont background-size: cover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a div #service_wrap it has an image that should cover 100%width of the page it works fine in firefox,chrome and edge. But IE 11 it centers the image and does not cover the div 
What is the IE equivalent of background-size: cover;

css

```
#service_wrap{
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:100%;
height:750px;
max-height:750px;
display:table;
background: url(../images/service_header.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

html

```
<div id="service_wrap" >

<div id="service_top" >
<h1>WE WORK CLOSELY WITH OUR PARTNERS TO GET YOU THE BEST SERVICE.</h1>
<h2>Click on a service below to learn more about how we partner with each one.</h2>
</div><!--service_top-->

<div id="service_bottom" >
<div class="services_holder">
<a href=""><div class="service1"></div></a><!--service1-->
<a href=""><div class="service2"></div></a><!--service2-->
<a href=""><div class="service3"></div></a><!--service3-->
<a href=""><div class="service4"></div></a><!--service4-->
<a href=""><div class="service5"></div></a><!--service5-->
<a href=""><div class="service6"></div></a><!--service4-->
<a href=""><div class="service7"></div></a><!--service5-->
</div><!--services_holder-->
</div><!--service_bottom-->

</div><!--service_wrap-->
```

[image: firefox]

[image: IE11]

If you insert the code below into a webpage on IE11 it does not use the full width

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>this is a title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/partners.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />

<style>

#service_wrap{

background: url(http://test.finelinewow.com/images/partner_header.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
} 
</style>


</head>
<body>








<!----------------------------------------------------------------service---------------------------------------------------------------->   

<div id="service_wrap" >



<div id="service_top" >
<h1>WE WORK CLOSELY WITH OUR PARTNERS TO GET YOU THE BEST SERVICE.</h1>
<h2>Click on a service below to learn more about how we partner with each one.</h2>


</div><!--service_top-->


<div id="service_bottom" >
<div class="services_holder">
<a href="#liberty_towing"><div class="service1"></div></a><!--service1-->
<a href="#auto_palace"><div class="service2"></div></a><!--service2-->
<a href="#discount_auto"><div class="service3"></div></a><!--service3-->
<a href="#speedy_car"><div class="service4"></div></a><!--service4-->
<a href="#solid_insurance"><div class="service5"></div></a><!--service5-->
<a href="#sevan_auto"><div class="service6"></div></a><!--service4-->
<a href="#gray_gables"><div class="service7"></div></a><!--service5-->
</div><!--services_holder-->
</div><!--service_bottom-->





</div><!--service_wrap-->

<!----------------------------------------------------------------/service---------------------------------------------------------------->  


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But `background-size: cover` works in IE11, so you must have something else wrong

Comment: not in windows 10 using the ie 11 browser

Comment: I am on Win 10 using IE11 and it works just fine

Comment: Try background: url(../images/service_header.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;

Comment: It works since IE9 : http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Exactly ... was just about to add that :)

Comment: well i dont know whats going on im using html 5, i have compatibility mode off, no zoom. ive taken out all the code except 1 div i

Comment: take my code snippet upload it to ur test server and u will see it does not cover the whole width of the page

Comment: I just tried your code and it works fine

Comment: can u screen shot for me?

Comment: http://test.finelinewow.com/partners.php   not working here difference pc win 7 ie 11

Comment: i got a 27 inch monitor, 1080p  , image is 1,500px × 885px so it should work but u see my screenshot and my code it should work but 3 different PC's do not

Comment: Here is a screen shot using fiddle: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gzH26.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

fixed the issue.
Code would work on local machine,jfiddle and codepen but when uploading the site the above code needed to be added to display correctly.

Comment: In my case, the issue had to do with SVG. Give it a width and a height. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840551/background-size-with-svg-squished-in-ie9-10